# Bitbucket pipelines dind "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon"

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to run end to end tests on a node repo but it needs the postgres container.  When I te

```
image: docker:dind

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Run e2e tests
        runs-on:
          - "self.hosted"
        script:
          - docker compose up db
```

I get `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?.`

I am using docker in docker image, but I keep getting that when I run the pipeline.

I have manually connected to the runner container and booted up a `docker:dind` container and was able to connect to that one and was able to start a `docker run posgres:latest`

I am so confused. The only difference I saw was my manual dind instance forwarded   `2375-2376/tcp`